# Low resolution of Math formulas in Wolfram Web Resources

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, webmathematica, mathematica-online

I use Wolfram Web Resources extensively, but unfortunately, all of the displayed math is in low resolution. Is there a way of viewing (and copying) math in high resolution?

For example: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the technical computing software Wolfram Mathematica.